# Calculate nunique() for groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with columns:

1. `diff` - difference between registration date and payment date,in days
2. `country` - country of user
3. `user_id`
4. `campaign_id` -- another categorical column, we will use it in groupby

I need to calculate count distinct users for every `country`+`campaign_id` group who has `diff`<=n.
For example, for `country` 'A', `campaign` 'abc' and `diff` 7 i need to get count distinct users from `country` 'A', `campaign` 'abc' and `diff` **<=** 7

My current solution(below) works too long

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## generate test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'country':np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 10000),
        'campaign': np.random.choice(['camp1', 'camp2', 'camp3', 'camp4', 'camp5', 'camp6'], 10000),
        'diff':np.random.choice(range(10), 10000),
        'user_id': np.random.choice(range(1000), 10000)
        })
## main
result_df = pd.DataFrame()
for diff in df['diff'].unique():
    tmp_df = df.loc[df['diff']<=diff,:]
    tmp_df = tmp_df.groupby(['country', 'campaign'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.user_id.nunique()).reset_index()
    tmp_df['diff'] = diff
    tmp_df.columns=['country', 'campaign', 'unique_ppl', 'diff']
    result_df = pd.concat([result_df, tmp_df],ignore_index=True, axis=0)
```

Maybe there is better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One alternative below, but [@jezrael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49298071/9209546) is optimal.

**Performance benchmarking**

```
%timeit original(df)  # 149ms
%timeit jp(df)        # 81ms
%timeit jez(df)       # 47ms

def original(df):
    result_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for diff in df['diff'].unique():
        tmp_df = df.loc[df['diff']<=diff,:]
        tmp_df = tmp_df.groupby(['country', 'campaign'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.user_id.nunique()).reset_index()
        tmp_df['diff'] = diff
        tmp_df.columns=['country', 'campaign', 'unique_ppl', 'diff']
        result_df = pd.concat([result_df, tmp_df],ignore_index=True, axis=0)

    return result_df

def jp(df):

    result_df = pd.DataFrame()
    lst = []
    lst_append = lst.append
    for diff in df['diff'].unique():
        tmp_df = df.loc[df['diff']<=diff,:]
        tmp_df = tmp_df.groupby(['country', 'campaign'], as_index=False).agg({'user_id': 'nunique'})
        tmp_df['diff'] = diff
        tmp_df.columns=['country', 'campaign', 'unique_ppl', 'diff']
        lst_append(tmp_df)

    result_df = result_df.append(pd.concat(lst, ignore_index=True, axis=0), ignore_index=True)

    return result_df

def jez(df):
    df1 = pd.concat([df.loc[df['diff']<=x].assign(diff=x) for x in  df['diff'].unique()])
    df2 = (df1.groupby(['diff','country', 'campaign'], sort=False)['user_id']
              .nunique()
              .reset_index()
              .rename(columns={'user_id':'unique_ppl'})
              .reindex(columns=['country', 'campaign', 'unique_ppl', 'diff']))
    return df2
```

Answer (score 8):

First use list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for join all together and then `groupby` with [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) with adding column `diff`, last rename columns and if necessary add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for custom columns order:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.loc[df['diff']<=x].assign(diff=x) for x in  df['diff'].unique()])
df2 = (df1.groupby(['diff','country', 'campaign'], sort=False)['user_id']
          .nunique()
          .reset_index()
          .rename(columns={'user_id':'unique_ppl'})
          .reindex(columns=['country', 'campaign', 'unique_ppl', 'diff']))
```